# Destiny Chat Exit

Tags: ps4, destiny

I left the fireteam in Destiny in the tower but did not leave the chat, even when I switched to a different game!  I felt dumb because I did not know how to exit the chat so I muted the mic but then was the subject of discussion. (awkward!)  How did I leave the fireteam but not the chat?  Was the chat somehow console (PS4) managed instead of destiny/bungie managed?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you joined a [Party Chat](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/party/about_party.html). This is a feature of the PS4 that allows people to communicate even when they aren't in the same game.

To leave the party chat:

- Press the Home Button to get to the main PS4 dashboard.
- Press Up to go to the options bar at the top.
- Find the icon for Party, it will look like this:
  [image]
- Enter the party screen by clicking "X", and you should see this:
  [image]
- Now choose "Leave This Party" on the bottom-right corner.

Comment: Thanks!  I did some more research, that's what happened.